# Yearling calculation wrong?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, yearling-badge

I've earned the "Yearling" badge once every year since 2009, about the first time it was possible. It was just awarded to me again today... but I'm pretty sure I joined the site in late August 2008, meaning this badge is almost two months early. What's up with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [got it on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=3043), not o[n Main](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=3043):

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 3):

When you hover over the *member for* entry you see the date you joined: today for 4 years.

[image: member for]

Comment: Maybe that's been messed up, too